# Flume with twitter api v2 baseURLs problem

Tags: endpoint, twitter4j, flume, twitter-api-v2

I'm trying to config twitter4j property file in Flume conf dir for changing the default api link and endpoints from v1.1 (which is deprecated) to v2 but only the streamBaseURL is changing, the endpoint is always the v1.1 api endpoints (statuses/sample)

Can someone help me to properly set my twitter4j streamBaseURL and endpoints to the twitter api v2's values of them ??

Nb: I'm using twitter4j v4.0.7